# How to build a Maven project using Freestyle Job In Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to use mvn clean install inside shell in jenkins. But it is giving errors and buid is failing.
Is there a way to build maven inside freestyle job?

Comment: Could you provide us the issue details what you are facing. Simply failing cannot give any clue to supporters to support you. It is like more generic now.

Comment: I am executing the maven command in a shell inside freestyle job and getting a error message - mvn: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure. Is there any other way to build a maven project inside freestyle job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 options to do this:

1. Install maven on the server jenkins is running on so you can run `mvn install` in a shell command.
2. Using the maven plugin, use "involve top level maven targets" as a build step. This will require picking maven versions to be installed in "Manage Jenkins" as well as the associated user and global Maven settings.

Answer (score 4):

There is a 3rd option: use the **Build Step** called **Invoke top-level Maven targets** in a Free-Style project, where you select a Maven Installation (see below), then set its goals (e.g., `clean install`, or `clean install -f subdir/pom.xml` (if your pom.xml is not in the root)).

This requires you to configure the "Maven" tool (via **Manage Jenkins** | **Global Tool Configuration**). Scroll down to "Maven" to "add" an installation (ignore the "Maven Configuration" at the top).

I like this because I don't have to install Maven and I don't have to add the Maven Integration Plugin to do this simple thing (although the Maven plugin does have other features that (better or worse) might be interesting to some folks).

Answer (score 2):

From the message what you have shared "mvn command not found" this is due to maven was not available or there is no maven_home declared in environment variables.

Follow the [article](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/212341468-Build-Step-Invoke-top-level-Maven-targets-does-not-show-version-dropdown) it explains how you can use Invoke top level maven targets steps in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

It's advised that you will use [Maven Project](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+maven2+project) instead of freestyle project

You have [Maven Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin) you can check [full installation](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/how-to-setup-jenkins-for-a-maven-project/)